# Is there two-factor authentication for hosted wordpress.com blogs?

Tags: security, authentication, multi-factor-auth, wordpress.com, google-authenticator

[There is a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-authenticator/) that supports two-factor authentication via Google's Authenticator for self-hosted Wordpress blogs. Is there a similar feature I can turn on for hosted [wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com/) blogs? Every search I do turns up the former mechanism...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two-factor authentication is now available on WordPress.com blogs.

Wordpress.com blogs now supports two-factor authentication both via **Google Authenticator** as well as **SMS**.

See [Wordpress | Two Step Authentication](http://en.support.wordpress.com/security/two-step-authentication/) for an how-to on setting it up.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the plugin isn't developed by WordPress and you can't install custom plugins on a wordpress.com blog, so no - at the moment there's no way to turn on two-factor authentication for Wordpress.com blogs

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, I'm not particular to _that_ plugin; any mechanism for two-factor would be fine, so I was wondering if wordpress.com had another one. But that clears up one possibility, thanks.